# How to use ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_coco in android app

Tags: tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-model-garden

I downloaded [ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_shared_box_predictor_320x320_coco_sync_2020_05_06.tar.gz) and untar it, found there is already a `tflite` file called `model.tflite`, I want to know how to use it in [android app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app), can I replace original `detect.tflite` at `object_detection` android demo app with this `model.tflite`.

If can, is there anywhere I need to modify too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming you mean [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app) but you need to change few things ... In TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java change the following values to

- input size = 320
- NUM_DETECTIONS = 100

P.S: You also need to add some missing label values in labelmap.txt which are wrongly added as ???

Comment: Yeah, you got me, i mean that demo app. I have changed `input size = 320` and `NUM_DETECTIONS = 100`, but run it emulator, it reports error : `Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (normalized_input_image_tensor) with 1228800 bytes from a Java Buffer with 307200 bytes.` Did you try it successfully ?

Comment: @WadeWANG try to set the value of TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED (located in DetectorActivity.java) to false, it should solve this problem

Comment: After i set TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED = false; it is still wrong, but the error became `Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor_3/BoxPredictor/BiasAdd) with shape [1, 5, 5, 36] to a Java object with shape [1, 100, 4].`. If you use netron to check these two tflite model, you can see their output is different, so i think there should be more codes need to change

Comment: @WadeWANG Yes i ran it successfully .. did you remove the "download_model.gradle" content? as its maybe re-downloading the default tflite model everytime you replace it with mnasfpn model

Comment: I disabled "download_model.gradle", but it still got the same error, would you mind sending the app project to my email box : wadewang96@outlook.com, then i will compare yours and mine to see on earth what the diffrence is.

Comment: @WadeWANG https://drive.google.com/file/d/1854Ly-1CHwY0q0Ee3q_FFGgol_WbIkyG/view?usp=sharing
I posted here in case anyone has the same problem

Comment: Great ! I hava sent the request ~

Comment: @WadeWANG sorry, now you can download it without a request (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1854Ly-1CHwY0q0Ee3q_FFGgol_WbIkyG/view?usp=sharing) .. the new ui in GDrive is confusing

Comment: I found our model.tflite are different ! My used `ssd_mobilenet_v2_mnasfpn_coco` model.tflite is older. Just now i go to model zoo page to redownload it, and find it is the same with yours, so that is to say, the official has updated the model file !